# From where do the words ad sh'yevulu sifoisechem mi lomer dai

Tags: talmud-gemara

I know where the beginning of the song comes from (malachi 3 10) but I always wonder where does the later part come from. I looked in the rashi nothing I looked up a gemara nothing I looked radak and all agree that the beginning (ad bli dai) means untill there is no more storage space. So now I ask: Mi Yodea where does the later part come from?

Comment: To what song do you refer?

Comment: @DoubleAA https://www.chabad.org/multimedia/music_cdo/aid/140682/jewish/Vaharikosi-Lochem-Brochoh.htm

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

It's from [Shabbos 32b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.32b.8?lang=bi):

> And if people give terumot and tithes, they are blessed, as it is
> stated: “Bring you the whole tithe into the storehouse, that there may
> be food in My house, and try Me now with this, says the Lord of Hosts,
> if I will not open you the windows of heaven, and pour you out a
> blessing, that there shall be more than sufficiency [ad bli dai]”
> (Malachi 3:10). The Gemara asks: What is the meaning of: More than
> sufficiency [ad bli dai]? Rami bar Rav said that Rav said: It means
> that the abundance will be so great that your lips will be worn out
> [yivlu], similar to the word beli, from saying enough [dai].